# How to speed up Google Storage File download?

Tags: node.js, file, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'am following the guide described at the https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html
to download a file from Google Storage, using a Google Cloud Functions and node.js.

```
var file = bucket.file(gcsEvent.name);
file.download(function(err, contents)
```

To download a 5mb file it take up to 5 minutes. 
How can I speed up the download?

Comment: Are you trying to download the file using the cloud function as proxy? or will this file be used in the function?

Comment: I use default google functions setting. Yes, the file will be used in the function and it will be uploaded into a bucket

Comment: are you running this on node 8? if yes, please try to move this to node 10, is your function and your bucket in the same region?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `gsutil perfdiag`? It will perform various operations and then generate a report that covers a variety of things that could impact performance (CPU and RAM utilization, network retransmission, etc.)